# How do I use Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory's IMemoryCache.CreateEntry and ICacheEntry?

Tags: c#, .net-5

i found this interface and i want to use it. But i dont understand how to use the Create function...

```
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory
{
    public interface IMemoryCache : IDisposable
    {
        ICacheEntry CreateEntry(object key);
        void Remove(object key);
        bool TryGetValue(object key, out object value);
    }
}
```

How to store something in CreateEntry when there is only the key not the value in the function call? How to store something in the key?

So i have this:

```
class RedisObjectTestCache : IMemoryCache
    {
        public ICacheEntry CreateEntry(object key)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Created key: " + key);
            return new CacheEntryTest() { };
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dispose");
            return;
        }

        public void Remove(object key)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Removed key: " + key);
            return;
        }

        public bool TryGetValue(object key, out object value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Requested key: " + key);
            value = "";
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and then i call it with the framework:

```
QueryCacheManager.Cache = new RedisObjectTestCache();
```

Can i somehow get the value?

Comment: Without looking at the docs, I'd guess that `ICacheEntry` gives you access to the contents of that entry.

Comment: The docs specify some [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.imemorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#extension-methods), seems like you can use the [Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.cacheextensions.set?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#Microsoft_Extensions_Caching_Memory_CacheExtensions_Set__1_Microsoft_Extensions_Caching_Memory_IMemoryCache_System_Object___0_) extension method

Comment: A few examples are available here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45751948/706456

Answer (score 5):

[The `ICacheEntry` instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.icacheentry?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) returned from the `CreateEntry` method has a `Value` property which you can set to the value you want to cache, along with several other properties you can use to control the caching.

There are also several [extension methods for the `IMemoryCache` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.imemorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#extension-methods) which provide shorthand ways of setting an item in the cache.

Comment: .NET does it the same way, look at the [implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions/src/MemoryCacheExtensions.cs#L44-L50) of the `Set<TItem>` method

Comment: There's a huge gotcha with `ICacheEntry`: the value won't actually be cached until you call `.Dispose()`! So make sure you do `using( ICacheEntry e = memoryCache.CreateEntry(...) ) { e.Value = value; }`. Kinda ironic that you can't _cache_ the `ICacheEntry` object as a proxy into the `IMemoryCache`.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer: Don't use `ICacheEntry` (directly) at all.

Instead, use *only* the `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.CacheExtensions` methods: `Set<TItem>` and `TryGetValue<TItem>` - specifically, the `Set` extension method handles `ICacheEntry` for you.

Note there's a slight gotcha with this approach: you have to be careful you're using consistent `TItem` type-parameters and `Object key` keys - e.g. if you cache a `List<String>`using `Set< List<String> >(...)` but later use `TryGetValue< String[] >` then your code will *silently fail* and return `null` - instead of complaining that a cached `List<String>` cannot be retrieved as a `String[]`. (Of course, you probably shouldn't be caching mutable types like `List<T>`, instead you should cache something like `ImmutableList<String>` and only retrieve items via a compatible interface like `IReadOnlyList<String>` (which means you can also store `String[]` and `List<String>` in addition to `ImmutableList<String>`).

### Longer answer: Don't retain `ICacheEntry` and call `.Dispose()` immediately after setting `.Value`

There's a huge <sub>(still undocumented)</sub> gotcha with `ICacheEntry`: while the design of the API surface of the entire `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory` library **implies** that the `ICacheEntry` object *represents* a named/keyed slot in the `IMemoryCache` that you can keep in a long-life'd field or `static` field - and can manipulate any time you like - **this is not the case**: the `ICacheEntry` returned actually represents an uncomitted cache entry - so simply setting `.Value` won't do anything until you call `.Dispose()` on the `ICacheEntry` (or use a `using(){}` block).

The `CacheExtensions.Set` method does this for you: [observe the `using ICacheEntry entry = cache.CreateEntry(key);`  line in `Set`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions/src/MemoryCacheExtensions.cs#L44).

So, by example, if you are going to use `ICacheEntry` directly, **do not use it like this as *it will not work***:

```cs
public class ThingDoer_Bad
{
    // DO NOT USE THIS CODE - IT IS AN EXAMPLE OF HOW IMEMORYCACHE IS MISUNDERSTOOD:

    private readonly IMemoryCache memCache; // From DI

    private const String CACHE_KEY = "TheThing123";

    private ICacheEntry? entry;

    public void AddThingToCacheOrOverwriteExistingThing( Thing thing )
    {
        this.entry = this.memCache.CreateEntry( CACHE_KEY );
        this.entry.Value = thing;
        this.entry.Expiration = whatever;
    }

    public void UseCachedThing()
    {
        if( this.entry != null )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( this.entry.Value ); // <-- This will appear to work.
        }
    }
}
```

...in the above code, the `ThingDoer_Bad.AddThingToCacheOrOverwriteExistingThing` method doesn't actually do anything useful - people might *think* it works because if you retrieve `this.entry.Value` it will return the stored `Thing` object, but the `Thing` object *won't be in the cache* - you'll just be working with an normal stored object-reference just with extra steps.

This is how you're meant to use it, by *not retaining `ICacheEntry`* at all and disposing it immediately:

```cs
public class ThingDoer
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache memCache; // From DI

    private const String CACHE_KEY = "TheThing123";

    public void AddThingToCacheOrOverwriteExistingThing( Thing thing )
    {
        using( ICacheEntry e = this.memCache.CreateEntry( CACHE_KEY ) )
        {
            e.Value = thing;
            e.Expiration = whatever;
        } // <-- The implicit .Dispose() call at the end of the `using` block is what actually triggers persistence.
    }

    public void UseCachedThing()
    {
        if( this.memCache.TryGetValue( CACHE_KEY, out Thing? maybeThing ) )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( cachedThing );
        }
    }
}
```

### Better answer: Use this strongly-typed `struct` to handle get/set of single items

```cs
public readonly struct TypedMemoryCacheEntry<T> : IEquatable< TypedMemoryCacheEntry<T> >
        where T : class
    {
        private readonly IMemoryCache cache;
        private readonly String       key;

        public TypedMemoryCacheEntry( IMemoryCache cache, String key )
        {
            this.cache = cache ?? throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof(cache) );
            this.key   = key   ?? throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof(key) );
        }

        public String Key => this.key;

        public void Set( T value, DateTimeOffset absoluteExpiration )
        {
            if( value is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof(value) );

            _ = this.cache.Set<T>( key: this.key, value: value, absoluteExpiration: absoluteExpiration );
        }

        public Boolean TryGet( [NotNullWhen(true)] out T? value )
        {
            return this.cache.TryGetValue<T>( key: this.key, out value );
        }

        #region Tedium

        public override Boolean Equals( Object? obj ) => obj is TypedMemoryCacheEntry<T> other && this.Equals( other: other );

        public Boolean Equals( TypedMemoryCacheEntry<T> other ) => StringComparer.Ordinal.Equals( this.key, other.key ) && Object.ReferenceEquals( this.cache, other.cache );

        public override Int32 GetHashCode() => HashCode.Combine( this.cache.GetHashCode(), this.key.GetHashCode() );

        public static Boolean operator==( TypedMemoryCacheEntry<T> left, TypedMemoryCacheEntry<T> right ) =>  left.Equals( other: right );
        public static Boolean operator!=( TypedMemoryCacheEntry<T> left, TypedMemoryCacheEntry<T> right ) => !left.Equals( other: right );

        #endregion
    }
```

...then by then storing `TypedMemoryCacheEntry<T>` as a field you don't need to worry about keeping track of consistent `TItem` parameters in every call-site:

```cs
public class ThingDoer
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache memCache;
    private readonly TypedMemoryCacheEntry<Thing> cacheEntry;

    public ThingDoer( IMemoryCache memCache )
    {
        this.memCache = memCache ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(memCache));
        thus.cacheEntry = new TypedMemoryCacheEntry<Thing>( this.memCache, key:  "TheThing123" );
    }

    public void AddThingToCacheOrOverwriteExistingThing( Thing thing )
    {
        this.cacheEntry.Set( thing, expiration: etc );
    }

    public void UseCachedThing()
    {
        if( this.cacheEntry.TryGetValue( out Thing? maybeThing ) )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( cachedThing );
        }
    }
}
```

Much simpler, imo - I don't know why something *useful and straightforward* to use like this wasn't included in the `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions` library.